# Is there a way to get .deb files of the installed packages via apper?

Tags: debian, package-management, kde

So I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE and I'm using Apper for package management. Now I'm wondering if it's somehow possible to get .deb files of the packages I installed over it (or that are listed/registered in it) so that I can use them for offline installation on another machine. Is that possible? If so: how?

Answer (score 2):

Apper is a gui for packagekit. Backends for packagkit is for example

1. apt  Debian and debianbased Distros.
2. portage  gentoo
3. pacman Arch and his derivates

and others.  So the deb's are in the folder

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

I personally use the cache for my reserve notebook only to spare traffic. and both installations were identical. for that I use on main notebook [aptoncd](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/) With [apt-cdrom](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-cdrom) i add the medium as sources to the other.

For complete offline installation may [apt-mirror](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Set_up_a_local_Ubuntu_debian_apt_mirror.html) to create a local repository the better way.